# What does `mv ./*` without specifying destination do?

Tags: rename, wildcards

I accidentally forgot to specify destination before hitting the Return key. Where does `mv ./*` without specifying destination move the files and directories under current directory to?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79882/what-exactly-did-mv-tmp-folder-do-to-my-filesystem/79883#79883

Comment: "I'm surprised that `mv` accepts 1 argument" It doesn't. It accepts all arguments the shell passed to it after expanding the `*`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If the last argument was a directory, you just moved all of the files and directories in your current working directory (except those whose names begin with dots) into that directory. If there were two files, the first file may have overwritten the second file.

Here are some demonstrations:

**More than two files and the last argument is a file**

```
$ mkdir d1 d2 d3
$ touch a b c e
$ mv *
mv: target 'e' is not a directory
```

**More than two files and the last argument is a directory**

```
$ mkdir d1 d2 d3
$ touch a b c
$ mv -v *
'a' -> 'd3/a'
'b' -> 'd3/b'
'c' -> 'd3/c'
'd1' -> 'd3/d1'
'd2' -> 'd3/d2'
```

**Two files**

```
$ touch a b
$ mv -v *
'a' -> 'b'
```

---

**Further explanation**

The shell expands the glob (`*`) into arguments for `mv`. The glob is usually expanded in alphabetical order. `mv` always sees a list of files and directories. It never sees the glob itself.

The command `mv` supports two types of moving. One is `mv file ... directory`. The other is `mv old-file-name new-file-name` (or `mv old-file-name directory/new-file-name`).

Answer (score 31):

First I'll make a test base - 5 files and one folder:

```
touch file1 file2 file3 file4 file5
mkdir folder
```

Next I'll run a test command. The `-v` option specifies that I want every command the shell executes to be printed to `stderr`. The `-x` option specifies that I want the same printed to `stderr` - *but* I want it done *after* the command is evaluated but *before* the shell runs it.

```
sh -cxv 'echo mv *'
```

#### OUTPUT

```
echo mv *
+ echo mv file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 folder
mv file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 folder
```

So you see that the command I feed the shell is `echo mv *` and the command the shell executes *after* `*` is expanded is `echo mv` followed by all of those files and the folder.

By default the shell will expand *globs* like:

```
sh -cxv 'echo file[1-5]'
```

#### OUTPUT

```
echo file[1-5]
+ echo file1 file2 file3 file4 file5
file1 file2 file3 file4 file5
```

This is a result of the `set [+-]f` glob function:

```
sh -cxvf 'echo file[1-5]'
```

#### OUTPUT

```
echo file[1-5]
+ echo 'file[1-5]'
file[1-5]
```

So when you run a command in a shell configured with default options like `mv *` the shell expands into the `*` word an argument list of all files in the current directory sorted according to locale. It does the syscall `exec(ve)` for `mv` *(essentially)* with this argument list appended. So `mv` gets all of the arguments as the shell globs them and sorts them. Besides doing `strace` to see these effects, you can use the debug out again like:

```
sh -s -- mv * <<\SCRIPT
sed -n l /proc/$$/cmdline
echo "$@"
SCRIPT
```

#### OUTPUT

```
sh\000-s\000--\000mv\000file1\000file2\000file3\000file4\000file5\000folder\
\000$
mv file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 folder
```

And portably:

```
( PS4= IFS=/; set -x mv *; : "/$*/" ) 2>&1
```

#### OUTPUT

```
: /mv/file1/file2/file3/file4/file5/folder/
```

Basically, the shell executes `mv` with the contents of the directory *(if it is not empty and not including files/folders with names beginning with `.`)* as its argument list. `mv` is POSIX specified to interpret its final argument as a directory if it is invoked with more than two arguments - in the same way `ln` is *(because, in fact, they're incredibly similar tools in underlying function)*.

Enough `echo`es though:

```
sh -cxv 'mv *' ; ls
```

#### OUTPUT

```
mv *
+ mv file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 folder
folder/
```

All of the files were moved into the final argument - because it is a folder. Now what if it is not a folder?

```
sh -cxv 'cd *; mv *'; ls . *
```

#### OUTPUT

```
cd *; mv *
+ cd folder
+ mv file1 file2 file3 file4 file5
mv: target ‘file5’ is not a directory

.:
folder/

folder:
file1  file2  file3  file4  file5
```

This is how [POSIX specifies](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mv.html) `mv` should behave in that case:

```
mv [-if] source_file target_file

mv [-if] source_file... target_dir
```

> In the first synopsis form, the `mv` utility shall move the file named by the source_file operand to the destination specified by the *target_file*. This first synopsis form is assumed when the final operand does not name an existing directory and is not a symbolic link referring to an existing directory. In this case, if *source_file* names a non-directory file and *target_file* ends with a trailing `/slash` character, `mv` shall treat this as an error and no *source_file* operands will be processed.
>
> In the second synopsis form, `mv` shall move each file named by a source_file operand to a destination file in the existing directory named by the *target_dir* operand, or referenced if *target_dir* is a symbolic link referring to an existing directory. The destination path for each source_file shall be the concatenation of the target directory, a single `/slash` character if the target did not end in a `/slash`, and the last pathname component of the *source_file*. This second form is assumed when the final operand names an existing directory.

So if `*` expands to:

- two files

  - You should have only one file, which is the first `renamed` to the second after the second is `unlinked`.
- one or more files followed last by a directory or a link to one

  - You should have only one directory or a link to one, which is where all its parent's previous contents have just been moved.
- anything else

  - You should have an error message and a satisfying sigh of relief.

Comment: yes, using the old `sh` thingy, I forgot about debugging with that, but regarding my original question, it means that the problem is the shell not `mv` ? That's nasty, it's simpler than I originally thought but it's a real trap .

Comment: So the current directory should not actually be empty, but contain one directory that holds the original contents of the current directory? What would happen if the final expansion by the shell is a file rather than a directory?

Comment: @user2485710 - getting there. And yes - Warwick is right - if you ran `mv *` you should have *one* file at least - as I intend to show.

Comment: @user2485710, the key point is that in Unix, the shell is responsible for expanding wildcards before passing the command line arguments to the command.  In Windows, each command has to expand wildcards itself.  This allows Unix shells to offer advanced wildcard facilities that work with any command.

Comment: @Warwick It should fail with "target `foo' is not a directory", where foo is the last argument.

Comment: @user2485710 If you are going to make a habit of it, you might want to alias your `mv` command to `mv -iv` but that is pretty painful.

Comment: @Warwick - I was one wrong. You should have one *dir* at least.

Comment: @user2485710 -  I was one wrong. You should have one dir at least.

Comment: @mikeserv given the fact that those files were not that important I rushed myself into cleaning up and skip to the next step, but I can confirm things as they now appear in my edit of my first post/question.

Comment: @mikeserv tl;dr, `*` is not a single argument? Right? :)

Comment: @Bernhard - actually, that's the one case I didn't cover - because it *might* be.

Answer (score 19):

First the shell expands `./*` to all files in the current directory (except files starting with a dot).

- if there is no or only one file: `mv` fails
- if there are two file: the first one is moved to the second (which therefore get lost)
- if there are more than two files:

  - if the last one is a directory: all files are moved into this directory
  - otherwise `mv` fails.

Comment: Thanks. how to tell which subdirectory is " the last one"?

Comment: Just call `echo ./*` do see which order your shell uses (usually alphabetical).

Comment: If it fails with one file why doesn't it say so?

Comment: @Noumenon I do not understand your comment. `mv` returns an error message if it is called with only one argument.

Comment: You are right. The same command from my history now gives `missing destination file operand after *filename*`even though yesterday it didn't.

Answer (score 4):

When you type `mv ./*`, your shell will expand `./*` before executing `mv`.

A few things to note:

- If `./*` is expanded into less than 2 arguments, `mv` will, logically, produce an error.
- `./*` will usually expand into every file (including directory) present in the current directory and not starting with a dot.
- You can control what `./*` expands into by reading the documentation of your shell (`man 7 glob` is an entry point to the topic). Different shells will have different options.

Answer (score 1):

> **What does `mv *` do?**

Here's a shorter answer:

The shell expands the wildcard `*` to a list of directory contents. Then the shell passes that full list to the command. The command never sees `*`.

The command `mv file1 file2 ... filen directory` will move file1 ... filen into directory.

### Example

Here I make a test directory containing three files

```
$ mkdir t
$ cd t
$ echo a>a; echo b>b; echo c>c
$ ls
a  b  c
```

You can't move multiple files into a single file

```
$ mv *
mv: target `c' is not a directory
```

Let's add a subdirectory

```
$ mkdir d
```

You *can* move multiple files into a subdiretory

```
$ mv *
$ ls
d
$ ls d
a  b  c
```

Comment: The command `mv file1 file2 ... filen directory` is very little likely to have anything at all to do with `*`.

Comment: @Mike: My answer points out that the last stage of [shell expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html) effectively transforms the latter into the former. Not knowing this appears to be the root of the OP's confusion.

Comment: yes, but my point is the shell would not expand `*` into `file dir` unless there is some locale in which `d` follows `f`.

Comment: @mikeserv: There is such a locale, my example is a cut & paste from Putty connecting to a CentOS 5.6 GNU/Linux system.

Comment: which locale is that? your example is `a b c d` which isn't `file ... dir`. I only commented at all because you don't mention the sort anywhere and say only that `*` becomes `file ... dir` which doesn't happen.