# Improve `mv` to require explicit specifying target?

Tags: mv

I have hit some errors due to not specifying the target properly when using `mv`. For details, see:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192242/mistake-of-using-rm
- [What does `mv ./*` without specifying destination do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84166/what-does-mv-without-specifying-destination-do)

Can we make `mv` more secure against such human errors?

Comment: How do you distinguish `mv *` from `mv foo bar baz`?

Comment: why not? . @muru

Comment: `*` is expanded by the shell - `mv` isn't even aware of it. As far as `mv` is concerned, it received a set of arguments as if the user had typed them in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way to add extra protection against errors like that is to put the following three aliases to your shells rc-file (~/.bashrc in bash case):

```
alias cp="cp -i"
alias mv="mv -i"
alias rm="rm -i"
```

The `-i` switch stands for interactive, and it will prompt you before overwriting or deleting files.

`rm` also has another adaptation of this:

```
-I                    prompt once before removing more than three files, or
                      when removing recursively.  Less intrusive than -i,
                      while still giving protection against most mistakes
```

Comment: Thanks. but isn't answering to each prompt tedious, if i don't make mistake and need to delete a lot of things? What to do then?

Comment: rm supports only prompting once when removing multiple files (i edited my answer with information regarding it).  It's hard to detect suspicious commands, especially since the expansion of *, ? {,}, ! etc is handled by bash.  mv and rm only sees the expanded file names as arguments, never the glob pattern.

Comment: Tim, you can bypass the `alias` definition by escaping it as `\rm ...`.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of `mv` has been burnt into the minds of admins and users for ages, not to mention nearly uncountably many scripts that call mv, so changing the user interface will break a lot. It'd be better to write a wrapper (or an entirely new tool) that expects an explicit target.

Answer (score 1):

A command has no way to know what wildcards were expanded to make up its arguments.

In zsh, you can add the [`noglob`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#index-noglob) modifier in front of a command to prevent wildcard expansion. This allows you to define a wrapper that rejects the call if the last argument contains wildcards.

```
mv_check_last_argument () {
  local last
  setopt local_options null_glob
  last=(${~${(P)#}})
  if [[ $#last -eq 1 && $last[1] = ${(P)#} ]]; then
    command mv $~@[@]
  else
    echo 1>&2 "Not running mv because '${(P)#}' is a wildcard pattern"
    return 125
  fi
}
alias mv='noglob mv_check_last_argument'
```

(Warning: untested code)

This of course deprives you of the ability of using wildcards when you intend to match a single destination directory, but that's usually not very useful because you can use completion instead. When you do want to use wildcards, use `\mv …` with a backslash to suppress the alias.

Mistakes with `mv` are easy to undo unless you've overwritten an existing destination file. To avoid overwriting the destination file, there's an easy way: run `mv -i` instead of `mv`. This way `mv` only does the job of moving a file, and prompts you if it would have to do the additional job of removing a file. Again, use `\mv …` to skip the alias and unconditionally overwrite the target if it already exists.

```
alias cp='cp -i' mv='mv -i'
```