# The destination location of command: cp -rf ../path/to/dir *

Tags: bash, wildcards, cp

I accidentally used this command:

```bsh
cp -rf ../path/to/dir *
```

rather than this:

```bsh
cp -rf ../path/to/dir .
```

Now I wonder where the directory is actually copied to! Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last file in sort order (in the current directory).

Remember it's the shell that expands globs, before `cp` sees anything. Also, globs come sorted, so if the current directory has files `foo`, `bar` and `xyz`, then `cp -rf ../dir *` expands to:

```
cp -rf ../dir bar foo xyz
```

The last file there is the one `cp` takes as the target, so it'd copy all of `../dir`, `bar` and `foo` to `xyz`.

And of course if the last one is a regular file:

```
$ ls
bar  foo  xyz
$ cp -r ../dir *
cp: target 'xyz' is not a directory
```

Related: [What does `mv ./*` without specifying destination do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/84166/170373)

Comment: I double-checked and you're right. The last output of `ls -lh` command is a directory. And yes, it contains the copied directory!

Comment: You're right again! It not only contains the copied directory, but it also contains the contents of the current directory as well!