# What does "mv *" do?

Tags: shell, mv

I just gave this command by accident

```
mv *
```

while I was in a directory, needless to say that the content of my dir is gone and I have almost no hope to recover it, luckily it wasn't something relevant, but I'm surprised that `mv` accepts 1 argument and it also does some business with a simple `*` .

What does this command do ?

I'm under Ubuntu with `bash`.

---

**EDIT:**

given `<rootName>` as the directory where you are in when you give the `mv *` command, I can confirm that you should end up having another directory with the same name inside your root, something like `<rootName>/<rootName>` .

The problem now is that I already trashed my `<rootName>` without caring too much about the its destiny, so I can't say what's inside `<rootName>/<rootName>`, but I think that the logic of the given explanation is pretty clear and I can easily imagine that all my files went there .